# Cant track down access violation 0xC00000FD

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

Im using VS2008 and My MFC application has started to crash when setting breakpoints or running to cursor. I get lots of errors like this:-

```
First-chance exception at 0x78a5727c (mfc90ud.dll) in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfffffffc.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in MyApp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

The call stack is not much left either it only lists code in NT.dll

```
>   00000000()  
    ntdll.dll!7c9032a8()    
    [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
    ntdll.dll!7c90327a()    
    ntdll.dll!7c92aa0f()    
    ntdll.dll!7c90e48a()    
    ntdll.dll!7c9032a8()
```

I am not able to find the problem using break points or stepping through my code. The application "seems" to run normally if run using F5 in VS.

Whats the best method to track this problem down?

Comment: Did you try enabling all exceptions in VS? Still it doesn't catch it?

Comment: Yes but after doing that I get another exception which I have traced back to right after the initial domodal is called.  My application is wizard based. Whne I do enable all exceptions the get the original problem as posted.

Comment: Rightclick your stackframes and load the symbols for ntdll. Wont solve anything, but more information cant hurt.

Comment: Is it just your copy of VS with the problems? Try running it under WinDBG (http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) and see if breakpoints work there. If so you'll know it's a VS problem (maybe an uninstall/reinstall will fix it).

Comment: Have loaded symbols in VS studio now get 

> 00000000() 
  ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler2@20()  + 0x26 bytes 
  ntdll.dll!ExecuteHandler@20()  + 0x24 bytes 
  ntdll.dll!_KiUserExceptionDispatcher@8()  + 0xe bytes 


and nothing else in the stack trace.

installing windbg now.

Comment: First of all get your symbols right, it's a waste of time debugging without them.

Do you have multiple threads in your application? Since you say it crashes "right after" your DoModal(), maybe you're trying to access some of your UI elements *before* they were properly initialized from some other thread. Have seen similar thing recently, just because someone considered "more threads will make it faster and better" without any thought put into statement.

Comment: The domodal exception at startup is now fixed. Its a know problem which has been in my project since the start but not caught till I enabled exceptions is VS as Naveeen suggested . Problem is outlined in MS KB article Q158552. 

Now back to my original post, My application is single threaded or  more correctly I have not created any threads. I am using the correct symbols. Im about to give windbg a a go.

Comment: Could you update your question with the newly discovered symbols loaded? ;)

Comment: I was not able to track down the code that caused the access violation so rolled back to a previous version which is now working. Thanks all for the help..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where is the stack overflow from your question title? Access violations generally indicate an invalid pointer dereference.

Use your revision history to find the first version where things started going *boom*, then critically analyze all pointer stuff going on in and around the code modified in that revision.

Comment: Typo should be access violation in the title. I could do and thought of that but the app has many months of work gone into it at this stage. I was hoping there would be a quicker way but if not then fair enough.

Comment: If it has many month of work gone into it, you are using some source control system, right? If not, start doing that *right now*. Seriously.

Comment: Yes. I have been using TortoiseSVN since the start.

Answer (score 2):

I will use my psychic debugging skills and tell you that you are overwriting a buffer that lives on the stack - specifically, you're writing too many zeros into a buffer that isn't big enough to hold it.

You've got the classic symptoms of a smashed stack - the first AV you hit is trying to access zero minus a few bytes - clearly an offset from your stack pointer into either your parameters or your local variables.  (I can never remember which ones are above the stack pointer and which ones are below.)  Then you have a bunch of lines that indicate the instruction pointer has been set to zero, which often happens because the function return addresses in the stack frames have been overwritten with zero values - because you overwrote the stack-based buffer and corrupted all the other important stuff on the stack.  As your program tries to return from the current function, it looks in the stack to see where it thinks it came from, sees the zero, and jumps right there.  Whoops!

Since your stack is trashed, you may not find the stack trace too useful; your stack frames are likely to be corrupted by this point.

Answer (score 2):

There are some "templates" on the web that some use for making their Windows programs
Instead of this in `WndProc()`

```
case WM_CLOSE:
     PostQuitMessage(SUCCESS);
     break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
```

We get this:

```
case WM_CLOSE:
    DestroyWindow(hwnd);
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(SUCCESS);
    break;
```

If `SUCCESS` is 0, `DestroyWindow()` gets a null-pointer which produces an exception
as the window is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has an option somewhere to break on first chance exception (don't remember exactly where it is, maybe an exception menu item in the debug submenu?) You want to turn that on and look at your call stacks the moment they occur.

There is also an option to turn on Microsoft Symbol Server, that would automatically download the matching symbols for whatever system dll you happen to see in the stack. (sorry, don't remember how exactly thats setup either).

Comment: It's under Debug | Exceptions | Win32 exceptions. The above exception looks strangely familiar to null pointer dereferencing.